# how can i get a 2D image taken at an angle to sit right on a mirror

Tags: camera

I am trying to use blender to create some product photography which features a 2D image of a product taken at an angle, sitting on a reflective surface - this reflective surface + background is made in blender.

As the image is 2D and taken at an angle the bottom edge doesn't 'sit' on the surface right - if you were looking at a mirror, the reflection would meet exactly at both corners on the bottom edge, but because blender is interpreting the image as flat with a funny shape - rather than 3d at an angle - the bottom edge looks wrong

I could be completely wrong but it seems like there should be some way of mapping the 2D image onto a 3d block at an angle so blender will recognise it as 3d not 2D

i'm completely new to the program but am willing to go away and read - please be gentle but firm in your answers :)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add an [image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand what you are asking.

Comment: "*Gentle, but firm*" - You are setting some high standards. The workflow you need is probably to (1) create a geometry for the photographed object as well (2) project the image onto the geometry (3) all 3d objects are going to use the geometry with the image as a texture for reflection / lighting

Comment: Reflecting a 2D photograph as if it is 3D is something that will only work at one particular angle (and camera FOV.)  At that point, it becomes something you can do as easily (more easily) through emission rather than reflection: simply setting the "mirror" to emit the photo, at a fixed arbitrary strength (1 is good).  What else do you need from your scene?

Comment: Leander - so far i have created a geometry from the image but how do i go about projecting the image onto the geometry? That sounds like what i expected but i dont know how to do it..

Nathan - all i really want is to be able to give a watery reflective floor and back to the image (as if the product is in a corner), to import the image into the scene i used 'import as planes', are you saying i should use an emissive material? and where is the mirror setting?

Comment: I would use [Blam](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam) to calibrate my camera, and [Project from View](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#project-from-view) to project a texture onto a model of the product.